# Can I call a pyspark process from an interactive bokeh plot?

Tags: pyspark, bokeh

I have a bokeh plot (interactive) that I would like to use on a large dataset on the backend.  Is there a way to have the bokeh spawn a pyspark job to collate the data on the server then return it so bokeh can plot it?

Answer (score 1):

It should also be possible to accomplish this using the second generation Bokeh Server. However, your question is so broad that it is impossible to provide any specifics. Developing such an example for the Bokeh server would make a great contribution to the Bokeh project that I expect would benefit many people. However, I expect developing it would also take a lot of discussion, collaboration, and iteration, which Stack Overflow is not very good for. (SO is good for self-contained answers to narrow questions.) Accordingly, I encourage you to bring this question to the [public mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh).

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript callbacks

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html

You can call a webservice with ajax, so I guess you can do anything you want.